# How do raw PDF data and convert it into another PDF file using a bash script?

Tags: bash, pdftotext

I am trying to convert raw PDF data into a PDF file to run `pdftotext` on.
The data from `file1.pdf` is the data I want. If I call the following:

```
cat file1.pdf > file2.pdf
```

`pdftotext` works fine on `file2.pdf`.

However, if I try to run the following:

```
VAR1=$(cat file1.pdf)
echo $VAR1 > file2.pdf
pdftotext file2.pdf -
```

I end up with the following errors:

```
Syntax Error (99): Illegal character ')'
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

Is there anyway I can use the latter structure? I need to do it this way since the bash script will accept the contents of a PDF file and not the PDF file itself.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: `cat file1.pdf > file2.pdf` and `VAR1=$(cat file.pdf)` have different source files.

Comment: Sorry about that--meant VAR1=$(cat file1.pdf)

Comment: First problem is that you're not quoting the variable: `echo "$var"`. Second problem that you can't fix: command substitution strips any trailing newlines. Shell is not an appropriate language for handling binary data.

Comment: Thank you for the response @KJ. As glenn has pointed out as well, it is an issue of a truncated string, so I'll have to find a way for the bash script to accept different parameters.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman, that clears it all up.